# Datatable date range serverside loopback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing a jquery data table that links up to loopback API that populates the table with a get, it has been initialised with all the functionality, but now I want to add a date range function to filter my date column to show the records between the specified dates and I am having a lot of trouble. here is the code:

```js
app.controller('IwsManifestController', ['apirest', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Portal', '$http', '$cookies', function(apirest, $scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, Portal, $http, $cookies) {
  apirest.restManifest.find({}, function(item) {
    console.log(item)
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#tablegeneral').DataTable();

    }, 1000);
    $scope.manifest = item
  });
}]);

app.directive('iwsManifestList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    controller: "IwsManifestController",
    templateUrl: "../html/Templates/reporting/iws-manifest-list.html"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>From:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="from" name="from"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To :</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="to" name="to"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id='tablegeneral' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>HOST NAME</th>
      <th>IWS APP NAME</th>
      <th>INSTALL PATH</th>
      <th>USERNAME</th>
      <th>IWS VERSION</th>
      <th>DATE INSTALLED</th>
      <th>RESPONSE_STATUS</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>HOST_NAME</th>
      <th>IWS_APP_NAME</th>
      <th>INSTALL_PATH</th>
      <th>USERNAME</th>
      <th>IWS_VERSION</th>
      <th>DATE INSTALLED</th>
      <th>RESPONSE_STATUS</th>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

    <tr ng-repeat="mmItems in manifest" on-finish-render="trade">
      <td>{{mmItems.id}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.hostname}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.iwsAppName}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.installPath}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.username}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.iwsVersion}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.ts}}</td>
      <td>{{mmItems.responseStatus}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```